# What is the curl command line to send this HTTP Post to Cakephp to upload a file?

Tags: cakephp, curl, file-upload, http-post

I am able to upload an image file to a cakephp 2.5.1 website through HTTP Post on a form. I would like to upload by using curl command-line utility.

Below is the HTTP Post from Chrome debugger after uploading a file C:\D.jpg

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1/project/add
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh-TW;q=0.4
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:68
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:toolbarDisplay=hide; __utma=96992031.1610470000.1402390313.1402390313.1402390313.1; __utmz=96992031.1402390313.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); CAKEPHP=pc44cq07s0gouhb76trmi9pl07
Host:127.0.0.1
Origin:http://127.0.0.1
Referer:http://127.0.0.1/project/add
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
_method:POST
_method:POST
data[picture]:C:\D.jpg
```

What is the command to use to upload the same file when using the curl command-line utility?

I have tried the following commands but none worked;

```
curl -d "data%5BUpload%5D%5Bpicture%5D:C%3A%5CD.jpg" http://127.0.0.1/project/add
curl -d "data[Upload][picture]:C:\D.jpg" http://127.0.0.1/project/add
curl --form "fileupload=@C:\D.jpg" http://127.0.0.1/project/add
curl -i -F name=test -F filedata=@D.jpg http://127.0.0.1/project/add
```

Comment: Why the negative point? I have tried several command combinations but still cannot get it. This is why I am asking on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question after several trial and error. But I wonder what the command should look like if more than one field is required to be updated. For this answer, only 1 field `picture` is added.

```
 curl --data-urlencode "picture=C:\D.jpg" http://127.0.0.1/project/add
```

Answer (score 1):

please try with this code:

```php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, _VIRUS_SCAN_URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// same as <input type="file" name="file_box">
$post = array(
    "file_box"=>"@/path/to/myfile.jpg",
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Also [refer this doc](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/httpsocket.html#HttpSocket%3a%3aput) for additional help.

Comment: I was looking for a curl command. This looks like php code. But thanks for making the effort to write the answer.